# How to plot time periods as separate lines using Jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart, diagram

I have data which starts and ends at a specific date (periods of time) and therefore I want to draw a diagram which shows not only the value as a point but as line on the X axis. How would you do that?

It should look like the following example:
[image]

Comment: Maybe a Gantt chart with shape annotations?

Comment: i dont really get your question? you post an example of what is should look like therefore have you already done it?

are you talking about some form of annotation on the xaxis outside of the plot window (gray)?